Deploying a Simple Node.js App to a K8s Cluster on Hetzner Cloud with Envoy Gateway
I'm trying to deploy a simple Node.js application to a Kubernetes cluster on Hetzner Cloud. The app listens on port 8080 and is designed to return "Hello, World!" when accessed.
Here is my basic Express app:
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const PORT = 8080;

// Define a route for the root URL
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('Hello, World!');
});

// Start the server
app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on http://localhost:${PORT}`);
});

My Kubernetes Cluster have the following setup

1 control plane node
2 worker nodes

I've also created a load balancer for the entire cluster and added both the control plane and worker nodes as targets like this:
resource "hcloud_load_balancer" "cluster_load_balancer" {
  name               = "cluster_lb"
  load_balancer_type = "lb11"
  network_zone       = var.network_zone
  delete_protection  = false
}

resource "hcloud_load_balancer_service" "load_balancer_service_master" {
  load_balancer_id = hcloud_load_balancer.cluster_load_balancer.id
  protocol         = "tcp"
  listen_port      = 6443
  destination_port = 6443

  health_check {
    protocol = "tcp"
    port     = 6443
    interval = 10
    timeout  = 5
    retries  = 3
  }

}

resource "hcloud_load_balancer_service" "load_balancer_service_http" {
  load_balancer_id = hcloud_load_balancer.cluster_load_balancer.id
  protocol         = "http"
  listen_port      = 80
  destination_port = 80

  health_check {
    protocol = "http"
    port     = 80
    interval = 10
    timeout  = 5
    retries  = 3
  }

}

resource "hcloud_load_balancer_network" "lb_network_cluster" {
  load_balancer_id = hcloud_load_balancer.cluster_load_balancer.id
  network_id       = hcloud_network.private_network.id
}

resource "hcloud_load_balancer_target" "load_balancer_target_master" {
  for_each = { for idx, server in hcloud_server.master-node : idx => server }

  type             = "server"
  load_balancer_id = hcloud_load_balancer.cluster_load_balancer.id
  server_id        = each.value.id
  use_private_ip   = true

  depends_on = [hcloud_server.master-node]
}

resource "hcloud_load_balancer_target" "load_balancer_target_worker" {
  for_each = { for idx, server in hcloud_server.worker-node : idx => server }

  type             = "server"
  load_balancer_id = hcloud_load_balancer.cluster_load_balancer.id
  server_id        = each.value.id
  use_private_ip   = true

  depends_on = [hcloud_server.worker-node]
}

Kubernetes Resources
To allow users to access my Node.js app externally via the load balancer, I created the following resources:
apiVersion: gateway.networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: GatewayClass
metadata:
  name: eg
spec:
  controllerName: gateway.envoyproxy.io/gatewayclass-controller
---
apiVersion: gateway.networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: eg
spec:
  gatewayClassName: eg
  listeners:
    - name: http
      protocol: HTTP
      port: 80
---
apiVersion: gateway.networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: HTTPRoute
metadata:
  name: example-httproute
  namespace: socials
spec:
  parentRefs:
    - name: eg
  rules:
    - backendRefs:
        - name: example-service
          kind: Service
          port: 80
      matches:
        - path:
            type: PathPrefix
            value: /
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: example-service-account
  namespace: socials
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: example-service
  namespace: socials
spec:
  selector:
    app: example
  ports:
    - name: http
      port: 80
      targetPort: 8080

Deployment Definition
Here is my pod deployment definition:
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: example-deployment
  namespace: socials
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: example
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: example
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: example-service-account
      containers:
        - name: example-container
          image: "redacted"
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
          resources:
            requests:
              cpu: "100m"
              memory: "1Gi"
            limits:
              cpu: "800m"
              memory: "2Gi"

Current Issue
However, whenever I visit the load balancer IP in the form http://<load-balancer-ip>, I get the following error:
503 Service Unavailable
No server is available to handle this request.

Firewall Rules
I have also added the necessary firewall rules as below, yet I can't seem to access my Node.js app from outside:
resource "hcloud_firewall" "k8s_firewall" {
  name = "k8s-firewall"

  rule {
    description = "Allow Incoming Requests TCP - Kube API Server"
    direction    = "in"
    protocol     = "tcp"
    port         = "6443"
    source_ips   = [
      "0.0.0.0/0",
      "::/0"
    ]
  }

  rule {
    description = "Allow Incoming SSH Traffic"
    direction    = "in"
    protocol     = "tcp"
    port         = "22"
    source_ips   = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }

  rule {
    description = "Allow Incoming HTTPS Traffic"
    direction    = "in"
    protocol     = "tcp"
    port         = "443"
    source_ips   = [
      "0.0.0.0/0",
      "::/0"
    ]
  }
  
  rule {
    description = "Allow Incoming HTTP Traffic"
    direction    = "in"
    protocol     = "tcp"
    port         = "80"
    source_ips   = [
      "0.0.0.0/0",
      "::/0"
    ]
  }
}

Despite all that, I can't seem to access my nodejs app from outside the cluster. I will really appreciate any help on this
